# vim autocomplete after "("

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I have c code like this

```
char path[512];
FILE *fd;

fd = fopen(pa
```

I want vim complete "pa" to "path", use c-n/c-x,c-n/c-x,c-o

but it not work, show "pattern not found"

I must add a space after "(", like this:

```
fd = fopen( pa
```

then it work, but I don't want add space after "(".

how can I make it work? thanks for any advice.

Comment: Have you tried using simple completion instead? In this case, `CTRL-P` (or `CTRL-N`).

Comment: yes, I have trid, It not work.

Answer (score 1):

Most completions use the *keyword* before the cursor as the completion base. It looks like you have included `(` in the `'iskeyword'` setting. (The default filetype settings for `c` do **not** add this!) If I'm right,

```
:setlocal iskeyword-=(
```

should fix the problem. Find out why and from where this got included then.